# How to get username of the user that I am viewing not the current logged in username

Tags: django, python-2.7, user-profile

I want to get the current profile viewing username and save it in `instance.user`. The problem is that I want to get the username of the user that is going to be rated for other users.

Here is my code:

```
def new_rate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            try:
                instance.rater = request.user
    --------->  instance.user = !!!!! GET THE CURRENT  PROFILE VIEWING USERNAME !!!!!
                instance.validate_unique()
                instance.save()
                form.save_m2m()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/' + request.user.username)
```

Comment: Why do you want to save it to the user that is logged in and you should also make this request a GET instead of a POST.

Comment: Firstly, DON'T SHOUT, it's rude, and don't use exclamation marks. And secondly, you haven't provided any useful information. What is the "current profile viewing username"? Where is it coming from?

Comment: You should ideally be sending the userid, or user slug as a part of the URL. Example `/rating/new/<user_id>/` and handling it that way.

Comment: @limelights that is completely wrong. Why should a form submission be a GET?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It shouldn't but this form submission should happen when the user is to be rated. What OP wants is to get the actual user id first and then post the rating. My wording could have been better.

Comment: sorry about my shouting. it's about emphasizing where is my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can only get `request.user.username` if your user is authenticated. To check it use `request.user.is_authenticated()`.

So I think it would look somewhat like this:

```
def new_rate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RateForm(request.POST)
        current_user = request.user
        if form.is_valid() and current_user.is_authenticated():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            try:
               instance.rater = current_user
               instance.user = current_user
               instance.validate_unique()
               instance.save()
               form.save_m2m()
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/' + current_user.username)
```

But to me, your design sounds flawed. If you already use request.POST, you should POST the current profile's ID.

If for example you're viewing URL `/users/500` and you have a form. Send the ID 500 and then in the view it should get the current profile user like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

def new_rate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RateForm(request.POST)
        current_user = request.user
        profile_id = request.POST['profile_id']

        if form.is_valid() and current_user.is_authenticated():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            profile_user = User.objects.get(pk=profile_id)

            try:
               instance.rater = current_user
               instance.user = profile_user
               instance.validate_unique()
               instance.save()
               form.save_m2m()
               # it should  return us back to that profile, not the request.user's
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/' + profile_user.username)
```

Comment: i am using a @login required decorator intead so no-one can reach this page unless he is loged in

Comment: Great! Then just omit the is_authenticated check and you're good to go